# Managing Arrays with a Class

Tags: php

Is it worth creating a class that does no work, but simply contains arrays of objects? The main benefit of having the class at all is that it provides a label for the collections that it contains.

For example:

```
class Park
{
    protected $benches; // array of Bench objects
    protected $people;  // array of Person objects
    protected $trees;   // array of Tree objects
}
```

Additional methods would include `addBench`, `getBench`, `addPerson`, `getPerson`, `addTree` and `getTree`.

Then the `Park` class could be used as so:

```
$park = new Park($benches, $people, $trees);

$tree = $park->getTree(0);
$tree->sway();

$person = $park->getPerson(1);
$person->walk();
```

The `Park` class is still not doing any work; it is only managing its components.

Is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Sounds like a marker interface

Comment: What would the name of the interface be? Would its methods consist of `addBench`, `addPerson`, etc?

Comment: I would call the class something like `ParkManager` since it is managing all the items contained in your park. I call it manager to represent that is controlling/managing a park,  not actually representing a park. The fact that it only operates on other classes and doesn't represent anything itself is no problem. Just call it a utility class.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Could you elaborate on the marker interface concept? Or is it not generally used in PHP?

Comment: Another benefit is that it could be autoloaded.

Comment: I'm not really a PHP guy, so keep that in mind. In java however there are several "marker interfaces" which are interfaces that don't really define anything. They just "mark" a class as having some property. An example from java is the [Serializable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) where it states "_The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable_".

Comment: @Takendarkk I guess I'm having trouble understanding what the interface would be "marking" in my example.

Comment: @Don'tPanic In the sense that the autoload would include all of the components in `Park` rather than loading each individually?

Comment: It marks that it manages a park. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @Takendarkk I think there is a disconnect between PHP and Java. I appreciate your help though. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. But trust me, I've used PHP plenty enough to know this is just fine to do and the concept is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87538/discussion-between-esswilly-and-takendarkk).